# Does growing up with digital technology make it easier to integrate with it?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience

I was watching a documentary called "Was geht noch ohne Internet" on the ARDmediathek, and in it, was discussed how it is difficult for old people to become internet literate. There were also exampls of how there are apparently pushbacks in other countries, for eg: [Spain](https://www.alamy.com/carlos-san-juan-the-78-year-old-man-who-has-collected-more-than-600000-supporters-with-his-campaign-soy-mayor-no-idiota-and-the-first-vice-president-and-minister-of-economic-affairs-and-digital-transformation-nadia-calvio-respond-to-the-media-in-front-of-the-media-after-registering-their-collection-of-signatures-at-the-ministry-of-economy-at-the-ministry-of-economy-on-february-8-2022-in-madrid-spain-san-juan-who-has-promoted-a-campaign-to-ask-for-a-more-humane-treatment-in-bank-branches-has-moved-from-his-farm-in-monteolivete-valencia-to-madrid-to-register-his-signatures-image528557739.html).

A comonly said thing in the documentary is that, for the young people the digital technologies are easier to use as they grew up with it, while it's difficult for old people because they didn't.

Does this common saying have a scientific basis, in sense that, it is more difficult for adult and older people to integrate with digital technology/learn usage of devices?

Comment: There are several tangled issues in this. Do you mean to ask about learning in general when you're older, or is the question to do with learning to use something you're unfamiliar with or to do with learning to use technology specifically? Could you focus your question a bit, and show some prior research.